# postgres fastest way to compare two nullable values

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to compare values including nulls in postgres, and am just wondering at the *fastest* way - I know I can do

```sql
where ((a = b) or (a is null and b is null))  
where (coalesce(a, 'SENTINEL_VALUE') = coalesce(b, 'SENTINAL_VALUE'))
```

just wondering which one of these is faster, and are there other options even faster?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest is:

```
where a is not distinct from b
```

However, I don't think that Postgres will use an index if one would otherwise be available.

Comment: ooh - I didn't know about that one - thanks - that's interesting